# replacing the integers in a string with x's without error handling

Tags: python, string, replace

I have been trying to figure out a simple way to replace the integers within a string with x's in python. I was able to get something ok by doing the following:

```
In [73]: string = "martian2015"
In [74]: string = list(string)

In [75]: for n, i in enumerate(string):
   ....:     try:
   ....:         if isinstance(int(i), int):
   ....:             string[n]='x'
   ....:     except ValueError:
   ....:         continue
```

This actually yields something like the following:

```
In [81]: string
Out[81]: ['m', 'a', 'r', 't', 'i', 'a', 'n', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
In [86]: joiner = ""

In [87]: string = joiner.join(string)

In [88]: string
Out[88]: 'martianxxxx'
```

My question is: is there any way of getting the result in a ***simpler manner*** without relying on *error/exception handling*?

Comment: Just a quick observation: try not to attribute something of `type <list>` to a variable called `string` as a good programming practices ;)

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, thanks for the tip; I will definitely make sure to remember that going forward :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, using regex and the [`re`](http://pymotw.com/2/re/) module:

```
import re

new_string = re.sub("\d", "x", "martin2015")
```

The string `"\d"` tells Python to search for all digits in the string. The second argument is what you want to replace all matches with, and the third argument is your input. (`re.sub` stands for "substitute")

Comment: If experience with `re` module, it can save much time and code line. It no doubt, it's best answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this

```
>>> data = "martian2015"
>>> "".join(["x" if char.isdigit() else char for char in data])
'martianxxxx'
```

The `isdigit` function will return `True` if all the characters in it are numeric digits. So, if it is a digit, then we use `"x"` otherwise we use the actual character itself.

---

You can actually use generator expression instead of list comprehension to do the same, like this

```
>>> "".join("x" if char.isdigit() else char for char in data)
'martianxxxx'
```

The only difference is generators are lazy evaluated, unlike the list comprehension which builds the entire list. The generator will give values only on demand. Read more about them [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

But in this particular case, with `str.join`, the list is built anyway.

---

If you are going to do this kind of replacement often, then you might want to know about [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

```
>>> mapping = str.maketrans("0123456789", "x" * 10)
>>> "martin2015".translate(mapping)
'martinxxxx'
>>> "10-03-2015".translate(mapping)
'xx-xx-xxxx'
>>>
```

The `maketrans` builds a dictionary with the character codes of values in the first string and the corresponding character in the second string. So, when we use the `mapping` with the `translate`, whenever it finds a character in the `mapping`, it will simply replace it with the corresponding value.

Comment: A list is still built using the generator expression with join, python does two passes so if you use a generator expression python first  needs to build a list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are correct. I left a note about that.

Answer (score 3):

change `isinstance` to `.isdigit`

```
string = "martian2015"
for i in string:
    if i.isdigit():
        string.replace(i, "x")
```

(or [regular expressions, regex / re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) )

Comment: It's `.isdigit()`, not `.isnum()` :)

Comment: yeah, was thinking in the wrong language again (or something)... whoops

Answer (score 1):

```
In [102]: import string

In [103]: mystring
Out[103]: 'martian2015'

In [104]: a='x'*10

In [105]: leet=maketrans('0123456789',a)

In [106]: mystring.translate(leet)
Out[106]: 'martianxxxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know advance data process method, you can invoke `string` module to filter num string.

```
import string

old_string = "martin2015"
new_string = "".join([s if s not in string.digits else "x" for s in old_string ])

print new_string
# martinxxxx
```

Although I know my anwser is not the best solution, I want to offer different methods help people solve problems.