# Check if a word contains a number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am tokenizing a string into words and then want to remove any word which contains a number.

```
tokens = ['hello', 'world', '12', '1-3', '23'']
```

As you can see, the numbers come in various forms. The above three are just examples. I can loop through the string items and see if there is a digit and remove that string. However, that doesn't seem right.

The isdigit() function doesn't work on such number-strings. How can I achieve this?

Goal: Any token which contains a digit should be removed. 
my current code is something like this which doesn't handle the above types:

```
relevant_tokens = [token for token in tokens if not token.isdigit()]
```

Comment: [`relevant_tokens = [token for token in tokens if not any(c.isdigit() for c in token)]`](https://ideone.com/WYIxED)?

Comment: This can help you :  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30141233/5596800

Comment: import re; result = [token for token in tokens if len(re.findall("\d+", token))==0]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works and I mentioned that approach in the question when I said: "I can loop through the string item". However, it makes my filter statement too complex. I was more looking for a single function.

Comment: Ok, the first thread linked actually contains the right regex solution, `re.search(r'\d', inputString)`. Do not use the `re.match('.*\d+', token)` solution below, it will cause unnecessary backtracking and slow down.

Comment: I'll use that option.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
tokens = [token for token in tokens if not re.match('.*\d+', token)]
```

Comment: `re.match('\d+', token)`
 won't detect `abc5`.

Comment: Fixed, @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @MohitC please update your answer based on the suggestions in the comments above so I can accept it, especially from Wiktor.

Comment: @engr_s simply `\d` will also detect `abc5` as a valid token which you dont want.